# SQL Query Java Net Beans

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Basically I have a table name java_db.Customer with the columns CustomerID,
Name, Address and FinanceOK.

Basically I want to write a simple query that says if FinanceOK = true JOptionPane.ShowMessage "Finance Accepted"

Otherwise FinanceOK = False JOptionPane.ShowMessage "Finance Declined".

What is the the best way to go about writing this query?

Comment: https://mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/

Answer (score 0):

Now, there's a lot of information in your post that is missing but down and dirty here is how you **might** accomplish the task:

```
long customerID_Variable = 232;   // .... whatever you have to provide customer ID number ....
String customerName = "John Doe"; // .... whatever you have to provide customer name ....
boolean financeOK = false;   // default financing approval flag
String message = "Finance Declined!"; //default message
        
// Catch SQLException if any...
try { 
    // Use whatever your connection string might be 
    // to connect to your particular Database....
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:c:/databases/salesdb jdbc:derby:salesdb");
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            
    // The SQL query string...
    String sql = "SELECT FinanceOK FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID = " + customerID_Variable + ";";
    // Although it is best to use the Customer ID  to reference a 
    // particular Customer you may prefer to to use the Customer
    // name and if so then use the query string below instead...
    // String sql = "SELECT FinanceOK FROM Customer WHERE Name = '" + customerName + "';";
            
    // Execute the SQL query...
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            
    //Retrieve the data from the query result set...
    while (rs.next()) { 
        financeOK = rs.getBoolean("FinanceOK"); 
    }
            
    //Close everything...
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
} 
catch (SQLException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
int msgIcon = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
if (financeOK) { 
    message = "Finance Accepted!"; 
    msgIcon = JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE;
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "Financing Approval...", msgIcon);
```

Comment: Suggesting to concatenate parameter values into the SQL String is a really, really **bad advice**. Use placeholders `?` and e.g. `stmt.setString()` to send the parameter values.